Will the Floyd's cycle detection algorithm, with the fast pointer having three steps jump work?
class SingleLinkedList {
    Listnode head; // instance creation is possible without creation of the object

    class Listnode { // classes and methods can be static or non-static
        int data;
        Listnode next;
        Listnode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
}

class SingleLinkedList1 extends SingleLinkedList {

    // Remove duplicates from a sorted linked list
    void delete_duplicate() {
        Listnode current = head;
        while (current != null && current.next != null) {
            if (current.data == current.next.data) {
                current.next = current.next.next;
            } else {
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    // Insert a node in a sorted linked list
    void insert_node_sorted_list(int x) {
        Listnode key = new Listnode(x);
        if (head == null || head.data >= key.data) {  // Handle empty list or head insertion
            key.next = head;
            head = key;
            return;
        }

        Listnode current = head;
        Listnode previous = null;
        while (current != null && current.data < key.data) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = key;
        key.next = current;
    }

    // Remove the first occurrence of a key from the list
    void remove_key(int x) {
        Listnode current = head;
        Listnode previous = null;
        if (head != null && head.data == x) {
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        while (current != null && current.data != x) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (current != null) {
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
    }

    // Detect a loop in the linked list using Floyd's Cycle Detection Algorithm
    boolean detect_loop() {
        Listnode fast_ptr, slow_ptr;
        slow_ptr = fast_ptr = head;
        while (fast_ptr != null && fast_ptr.next != null) {
            fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
            if (slow_ptr == fast_ptr) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Find the starting node of a loop in the linked list
    Listnode start_node_of_loop() {
        Listnode fast_ptr = head;
        Listnode slow_ptr = head;
        while (fast_ptr != null && fast_ptr.next != null) {
            fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
            if (fast_ptr == slow_ptr) {
                return get_the_starting_node(slow_ptr);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Helper function to find the starting node of a loop
    Listnode get_the_starting_node(Listnode slow_ptr) {
        Listnode temp = head;
        while (slow_ptr != temp) {
            temp = temp.next;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleLinkedList1 sll = new SingleLinkedList1();
        sll.head = sll.new Listnode(1);
        Listnode second = sll.new Listnode(2);
        Listnode third = sll.new Listnode(3);
        Listnode fourth = sll.new Listnode(3);
        Listnode fifth = sll.new Listnode(5);
        Listnode sixth = sll.new Listnode(5); // 1-->2-->3-->3-->5-->5

        sll.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;
        fourth.next = fifth;
        fifth.next = sixth;
        sixth.next = third; // Creating a loop

        System.out.println(sll.detect_loop()); // Detect if there's a loop

        Listnode startNode = sll.start_node_of_loop();
        if (startNode != null) {
            System.out.println("Start of loop: " + startNode.data); // Print the start of the loop
        } else {
            System.out.println("No loop detected.");
        }
    }
}

Will the Floyd's algorithm for cycle detection work if the fast pointer has the three steps as jump instead of two?
Can the Floyd's algorithm work if the fast pointer has steps jump are 3,4,5,7 ..etc?


We lack an example. Get us the rest of the code, so we can run it. Or better yet: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 2) What algorithm are you talking about? Floyd-Warshall? Please be more specific in your question.


So what is holding you back to test your premise?

It does always work.
If the list has a lead of A nodes and a cycle of B nodes, then Floyds algorithm with a multiplier of k will find a cycle after x steps, when x >= A and x % B == kx % B.
That will always happen when x >= A and x is a multiple of B.
